# How to keep firefox windows open and manage tabs in C# Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to learn how to use C# Selenium to control Firefox.
my question is how can I open a new tab and update an existing tab Url (and all of them are in same Firefox window) through C# Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

To open new tabs you could use JavaScriptExecutor like this

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');");
```

To close the current tab

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(“body”)).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w');
```

To switch between tabs I use this method, you need to provide the window Tittle:

```
public void SwitchToWindow(Expression<Func<IWebDriver, bool>> predicateExp)
{
    var predicate = predicateExp.Compile();
    foreach (var handle in driver.WindowHandles)
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
        if (predicate(driver))
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unable to find window with condition: '{0}'", predicateExp.Body));
}

SwitchToWindow(driver => driver.Title == "Title of your new tab");
```

Comment: thanks. also is there any method like c# internal web browser events to run some code while a tab is loading such as DocumentCompleted or WebBrowserNavigated and etc.?

Comment: I think it doesn´t have any event for this. Also you can check for an element of the new tab to know its state like this: driver.findElement(By.xpath("element")).isDisplayed()